# Get CultureInfo from current visitor and setting resources based on that?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I (in ASP .NET MVC) get the CultureInfo of the current visitor (based on his/her browser languages)?

I have no idea where to start. I tried looking into the "Accept-Languages" header sent by the browser. But is that the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Asp.Net Core version: using **RequestLocalization** ie the culture is retrieved form the  HTTP Request.

in Startup.cs - Configure

```
app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

Then in your Controller/Razor Page.cs

```
var locale = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
var BrowserCulture = locale.RequestCulture.UICulture.ToString();
```

Comment: This is a much better answer.

Comment: Razor pages in Get/Post methods, you can either go via Request or access the HttpContext directly. No need for a controller.
The RequestCulture offers 2 properties: Culture and UICulture.
You may need the Culture instead of the UICulture.

Answer (score 61):

[Request.UserLanguages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx) is the property you're looking for. Just keep in mind that this array may contain arbitrary (even non-exsitent) languages as set by request headers.

**UPDATE**

Example:

```
// Get Browser languages.
var userLanguages = Request.UserLanguages;
CultureInfo ci;
if (userLanguages.Count() > 0)
{
    try
    {
        ci = new CultureInfo(userLanguages[0]);
    }
    catch(CultureNotFoundException)
    {
         ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    }
}
else
{
    ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
}
// Here CultureInfo should already be set to either user's prefereable language
// or to InvariantCulture if user transmitted invalid culture ID
```

Comment: What types of values does these headers normally contain? Examples would be great to work with.

Comment: Quote: `Typically these consist of a two-character codes for the language, a hyphen, and a two-character code for the culture, such as "en-us" for U.S. English and "fr-ca" for Canadian French.`. So it's a `string[]` array containing values like those.

Comment: I've just been working with this, so just for anyone looking at this in the future, Request.UserLanguages is essentially a comma separated version of Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"].

The first item in the array will just be the country code (e.g. 'en-GB') and subsequent items will usually contain a 'weighting' (e.g. 'en-US;q=0.8'), for example mine is "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6" so you also might need to split each item again to find the actual code and the weighting.

Comment: The general form of these language tags is specified in RFC 5646 ( http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5646 ).  If you assume "ab-CD", you'll get thrown when somebody specifies an alphabet (sd-Arab-PK).

Comment: @SteveHoward: True. Also this information comes just from the header which can be freely modified on client and contain just anything, ranging from short two-character language code (i.e. "en") to arbitrary string (i.e. "I-am-a-cool-hax0RR!").

Comment: I'm actually running into this at work which is why I brought it up.  For Taiwan, IE9- sends "zh-TW".  IE10+ sends "zh-Hant-TW".  I don't actually care about malicious users since they're just going to get fallback stuff, I do care about how there are now multiple ways to "spell" a particular locale.

Comment: is it possible to give me a brief explanation about what is the duty of InvariantCulture? and what if user do not have any language in their preferred language list ? thank you very much @SergeyKudriavtsev

Comment: Be careful, this answer does not handle: choosing the best culture from the *user list*, taking care of the priority value, setting the current culture for resource localization.

Answer (score 7):

You can use code similar to the following to get various details from your user (including languages):

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
string browser = HttpContext.Request.Browser.Browser;
string version = HttpContext.Request.Browser.Version;
string type = HttpContext.Request.Browser.Type;
string platform = HttpContext.Request.Browser.Platform;
string userAgent = HttpContext.Request.UserAgent;
string[] userLang = HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages
```

Answer (score 6):

It appears `Request.UserLanguages` is not available in later mvc versions (Asp.net core mvc 2.0.2 didn't have it.)

I made an **extension method** for `HTTPRequest`. Use it as follows:

```
var requestedLanguages = Request.GetAcceptLanguageCultures();
```

The method will give you the cultures from the `Accept-Language` header in order of preference (a.k.a. "quality").

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    public static IList<CultureInfo> GetAcceptLanguageCultures(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        var requestedLanguages = request.Headers["Accept-Language"];
        if (StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedLanguages) || requestedLanguages.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var preferredCultures = requestedLanguages.ToString().Split(',')
            // Parse the header values
            .Select(s => new StringSegment(s))
            .Select(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse)
            // Ignore the "any language" rule
            .Where(sv => sv.Value != "*")
            // Remove duplicate rules with a lower value
            .GroupBy(sv => sv.Value).Select(svg => svg.OrderByDescending(sv => sv.Quality.GetValueOrDefault(1)).First())
            // Sort by preference level
            .OrderByDescending(sv => sv.Quality.GetValueOrDefault(1))
            .Select(sv => new CultureInfo(sv.Value.ToString()))
            .ToList();

        return preferredCultures;
    }
}
```

Tested with `ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0.2`

It's similar to @mare's answer, but a bit more up-to-date and the q (quality) is not ignored. Also, you may want to append the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to the end of the list, depending on your usage.

Comment: `StringWithQualityHeaderValue` - useful

Comment: @Phil, yeah, it's great. Parsing the header yourself would be a mess. There are a lot of little assumptions that could bite you.

Comment: `new CultureInfo(sv.Value.ToString())` is likely to crash with a CultureNotFoundException if the client gives an invalid culture name!

Comment: @SandRock That is a good note to those using this. I'm not handling the exeptions for you. It's a good idea watch for a `CultureNotFoundException` and return a `400` or `500` or something to let them know you don't have that language support.

Answer (score 5):

I am marking this question for myself with a star and sharing here some code that essentially turns the `Request.UserLanguages` into an array of CultureInfo instances for further use in your application. It is also more flexible to work with CultureInfo than just the ISO codes, because with CultureInfo you get access to all the properties of a culture (like Name, Two character language name, Native name, ...):

```
        // Create array of CultureInfo objects
        string locale = string.Empty;
        CultureInfo[] cultures = new CultureInfo[Request.UserLanguages.Length + 1];
        for (int ctr = Request.UserLanguages.GetLowerBound(0); ctr <= Request.UserLanguages.GetUpperBound(0);
                 ctr++)
        {
            locale = Request.UserLanguages[ctr];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(locale))
            {

                // Remove quality specifier, if present.
                if (locale.Contains(";"))
                    locale = locale.Substring(0, locale.IndexOf(';'));
                try
                {
                    cultures[ctr] = new CultureInfo(locale, false);
                }
                catch (Exception) { continue; }
            }
            else
            {
                cultures[ctr] = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            }
        }
        cultures[Request.UserLanguages.Length] = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

HTH

Answer (score -6):

`var userLanguage = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;`

Comment: this gets current culture from server not client's browser