# How to format number as money using regex

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I'm trying to format number into amount format using regex like below.

```
  var input = "1234567.00"
  var pattern = @"\d(?=(\d{3},?)+\.)";
  var replacement = "$$$&,";

  var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Which gives me $1,23$4,567.00 (extra $).

I want like below

```
Input:1234567.00 or 1234,567.00 or 1234567 should return $1,234,567.00
```

Please suggest correct one.

Comment: what you want get ? as result?

Comment: @SL5net Updated. Please check

Comment: How using regex? you don't. Parse it to a decimal and use the string formatting options to convert it to a string in currency format...

Comment: Why do yo not use ToString("C") and check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600344/c-sharp-tostringc-converting-the-decimal-to-currency-value-pound-instead-of

Comment: "if all you have is a regex, everything looks like a string operation."

Comment: my first prototype: `[^,\.\d](\d{3}?)(\d+,?\d*)([\.](\d{2}))?\b` to `$1,$2.$3` But you need to programm a line with to add you .00 in some cases https://imgur.com/a/tWvvVPi

Comment: second prototype `[^,\.\d](\d+?,?\d*?)(\d{3})?([\.](\d{2}))?\b` https://imgur.com/a/tWvvVPi i think it could not be done with pure regEx. needs additional a little programmed in c#

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at MSDN documentation [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimaldigits?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var input = "1234567.00";
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false ).NumberFormat;
var currencyValue = decimal.Parse(input);
var output = currencyValue.ToString( "C", nfi );
```

Comment: I mentioned clearly using regex. Above your sample stuff is well known. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52215475/73070) has the correct answer to your actual (non-regex) problem. This isn't something you can easily, or even should do with regex. There are limits. It's like asking »How can I establish a database connection with `Console.WriteLine`?« It's that kind of nonsensical.

You can do so in one replacement, if you absolutely, desperately have to:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"^|(\d{3}(?=(\d{3})*(\.|$)))", m => m.Value == "" ? "$" : "," + m.Value);
```

This will add a `$` in the beginning, and insert commas accordingly. It will also ignore regional settings, currency symbol and other things that the other answer gets right.

Comment: How can I establish a database connection with Console.WriteLine? Good example.. thanks for answering

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this:

```
//.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, "$1,").replace(/(.*\d)/g, '$$$1');
var input = "1234567.00";

var commaPattern = @"(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\b)";
var commaReplacement = "$1,";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, commaPattern, commaReplacement);

var dollarPattern = @"(.*\d)";
var dollarReplacement = "$$$1";
output = Regex.Replace(output, dollarPattern, dollarReplacement);
```

Gives $1,234,567.00

Comment: Why down vote? @noxsoul, is it possible to combine both regex?