# get culture info from users browsers for multi language website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multilingual

I have found this link as a guide to make a multi language website which it should run with users preferred language which they have set on their browsers.

[Get CultureInfo from current visitor and setting resources based on that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414123/get-cultureinfo-from-current-visitor-and-setting-resources-based-on-that)

as you see it has this code to do it

```
// Get Browser languages.
 var userLanguages = Request.UserLanguages;
 CultureInfo ci;
 if (userLanguages.Count() > 0)
  {
   try
    {
      ci = new CultureInfo(userLanguages[0]);
    }
   catch(CultureNotFoundException)
    {
     ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    }
   }
    else
     {
        ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
     }
    // Here CultureInfo should already be set to either user's preferable language
   // or to InvariantCulture if user transmitted invalid culture ID
```

but my question is that I do not know what exactly is the duty of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and it does not work at all in my project. it is always null.

I changed the code to this , It works fine but I am not sure about possible exceptions may it have. I really appreciate any kind of help.
here is what I have and it works completely fine but just not sure about possible exceptions. I want the default language to be `"en-US"`

```
  public ActionResult Index()
{
    CultureInfo ci;
    var userLanguages = Request.UserLanguages;


    if (userLanguages == null)
    {
        ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    }

    else if (userLanguages.Count() > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            ci = new CultureInfo(userLanguages[0]);
        }
        catch (CultureNotFoundException)
        {
            ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    }

    return RedirectToAction(ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName, "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code look fine, if user transmitted invalid culture ID it will use the "`en-US`" culture!

The `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` property is used if you are formatting or parsing a string that should be parseable by a piece of software independent of the user's local settings.

The default value is `CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture` so the default `CultureInfo` is depending on the executing OS's settings.

The code bellow should work as well to set the culture:

```
    private static bool DoesCultureExist(string cultureName)
    {
        return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Any(culture => string.Equals(culture.Name, cultureName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CultureInfo ci;
        var userLanguages = Request.UserLanguages;

        if (DoesCultureExist(userLanguages?[0]))
        {
            ci = new CultureInfo(userLanguages[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        }

        return RedirectToAction(ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName, "Home");
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much it seems more logical. let me check it. thank you

Comment: it confronts error in this line `  if (DoesCultureExist(userLanguages[0]))` when `userLanguages` is null. I mean when user did not choose any languages in the preferred language list of users browser. should I handle this?

Comment: It might work if you add a "?" DoesCultureExist(userLanguages?[0])

Comment: I tried but new errors happened. it does not recognise this `DoesCultureExist(userLanguages?[0])`