# Number Formatting with decimals

Tags: c#, format, numbers, cultureinfo

Hi i have a us number with decimal, which i try to convert to a danish number format. But somehow, i does not convert correctly

```
  CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
  CultureInfo dk = new CultureInfo("da-DK");


  double data = double.Parse("98.5");
  Console.WriteLine(data.ToString("N", dk));
```

My understanding is that .5 is the decimal i my instance. What i am trying to acheive is to make in into
98,5 instead. But when i try to do the following in my test code, it returns 985,0.

I need it to happen dynamic. A user could have saved the value as a string "98.5", and when he visit the value, it will be displayed correct because it displays in his culture.. But what if a different user, with a different culture visits the value. Then i would not be able to use cultureInfo "us" and "dk"?

Comment: try `double.Parse("98.5", us)`

Comment: Danish uses a comma instead of a period for decimal places I believe

Comment: @Bizhan You comment worked. But how would i know if the previous value was us? 

Any way to make i dynamic? what if the value was Australian or something else different from danish

Comment: Sounds like a business issue to me

Comment: Also see this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54129270/366064

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will work for you.

```
CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo dk = new CultureInfo("da-DK");


double data = 98.5;
Console.WriteLine(data.ToString("N1", dk));
```

Comment: It works, now i just have to figure out, how to convert the data dynamic.

Like if the user entered the value as 98,5, and then switched language to us, then the value should be displayed as 98.5

Comment: @Mags ` double data = double.Parse("98,5", dk); Console.WriteLine(data.ToString("N1", us)); `

Comment: What if i don't know what way the value was stored, only that it was stored as a string, and i dont know what culture the user has, that see the value. Then i couldn't write us or dk in ToString()

Comment: you should know the culture, otherwise, it will work as default.

Comment: The problem is i don't. I only have the string, and then somehow has to figure out what format, the user had who saved the value, and then parse it to a new format, when a user with different culture sees it

Comment: @Mags you can use Regex to check the value based on the pattern you can decide, but I don't think that is a good solution. you can know the current culture, but can not know the format